# Issue with preg_replace_callback_array

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

The function below checks for multiple regex parsed but its not working and i couldn't spot where am getting it wrong.

```
function getig($string)
{
$string = preg_replace_callback_array(
[
    "/\[instagram=(.+?)\]/" => function($matches) { 
    $pid=$matches[1];
    $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=$pid");
    $result = json_decode($result);
    return $result->html; },
    "/https?\:\/\/(?:www.)?instagram.com\/p\/(.+\/?)/" => function($matches) 
{ 
    $pid=$matches[1];
    $urlen=urlencode($url);
    $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=https://instagr.am/p/$pid");
    $result = json_decode($result);
   return $result->html; },
    "#\[ig\](.*?)\[/ig\]#is" => function($matches) { 
   $pid=$matches[1];
    $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=$pid");
  $result = json_decode($result);
 return $result->html; }
    ], $string);
  return $string;
 }
```

Comment: Please Edit the question with the desired result or errors you get, we are not here to guess what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that sticks out to me is that the dot in `.com` is not
escaped. It probably should be, otherwise it is a metacharacter that matches
anything but newline's.

Before

```
 https?\://
 (?: www . )?
 instagram . com/p/
 ( .+ /? )                     # (1)
```

After

```
 https?://
 (?: www \. )?
 instagram \. com/p/
 ( .+ /? )                     # (1)
```

Stringed

`"/https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?instagram\.com\/p\/(.+\/?)/"`

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in my code. Where am getting things wrong is that am on PHP5.6 and preg_replace_callback_array() only available in PHP7.